# Python Pandas & operator not returning right values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, truthy

In the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[False, 0], [False, 1], [False, 2], [False, 2], [False, 3], [False, 4], [False, 5]], 
        columns=['cond1', 'cond2'])
df['test'] = (~df['cond1']) & (df['cond2'])
```

I'm expecting to get in the `test` column the value `True` in all rows except the first, as the truthy value of any number but 0 is `True`. However, I'm getting `False` where the value in `cond2` is 2 or 4. Why?

The output of the above code:

```
   cond1 cond2 test

0  False 0     False 

1  False 1     True 

2  False 2     False 

3  False 2     False 

4  False 3     True 

5  False 4     False 

6  False 5     True
```

Comment: I makes sense if you see `&` as the bitwise operator, not boolean.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing "&" operation with pandas column, python can't interpret the other numbers. It's doing set operation instead of boolean operation. Therefore, you need to help it by converting to bool the second column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[False, 0], [False, 1], [False, 2], [False, 2], [False, 3], [False, 4], [False, 5]], 
        
columns=['cond1', 'cond2'])

df['test'] = (~df['cond1']) & ((df['cond2'].astype(bool)))
```